# In a finite field with characteristic 2, can I calculate the log(K+1) based on the log(K)?

Tags: finite-fields

In the equation $ a^x = a^y + 1$ over a finite field $\text{GF}(2^n)$, where '$a$' is the primitive element, can one calculate $x$ as a function of $y$ without having to resort to taking the logarithm of $(a^y + 1)$?

I.e. calculate $x$ as a function of $y$, without using "$\text{log}(k)$" as part of this function.

I need to implement this in hardware, and using the $\text{log}()$ function is very costly, so I was thinking if there is a smarter way to do it.

Regards,

-Dimitri

Comment: I don't believe that you can. this function is known as a *Zech logarithm* and, for carrying out fast computations in moderately small finite fields, it is standard to store their values in a lookup table.

Comment: Derek, thank you for your answer and for mentioning Zech logarithm. I had not heard of that before.

Comment: This logarithm is a lot cheaper today than two years ago. http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.4244

Comment: If $n\le 16$ (or may be a bit larger?), then a look-up table will do this for you. If you work on crypto, and your $n$ is in the 3-digit range, then that won't do. Index calculus may help, but may be slower than you can stomach. But that is a generic method, and won't allow you to take advantage of the known $y$.